# Implementing Luong and Manning's hybrid model

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, nlp, keras, stanford-nlp

[hybrid word character model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBeCj.png)

As shown in the above image I need to create a **hybrid** encoder-decoder network(seq2seq) which takes in both word and character embeddings as input.
As shown in image consider the sentence:

> *A cute cat*

Hypothetically the words in vocabulary are:

> a , cat

and Out of vocabulary words are:

> cute

we feed the words **a, cat** as their respective embeddings
but since **cute** is out of vocabulary we generally feed it with embedding of a universal token.

But instead in this case I need to pass that unique word (*cute* which is out of vocabulary) through another seq2seq layer **character by character** to generate its embedding on the fly.

The both seq2seq layers must be trained jointly end to end.
The following is a snippet of my code where I tried the main encoder decoder network which takes word based inputs in **Keras**

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(X_vocab_len+y_vocab_len, 300,weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=X_max_len, mask_zero=True))
for i in range(num_layers):
    return_sequences = i != num_layers-1
    model.add(LSTM(hidden_size,return_sequences=return_sequences))



model.add(RepeatVector(y_max_len))

# Creating decoder network
for _ in range(num_layers):
    model.add(LSTM(hidden_size, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(y_vocab_len)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        optimizer='rmsprop',
        metrics=['accuracy'])
```

**here X is my input sentence and y is the sentence to be generated ,vocabulary size is what I fixed consisting of frequent words and rare words are considered out of vocabulary based on vocabulary size**

here I created a sequential model in Keras where I added embeddings from pre-trained vectors generated by GloVe(embedding_matrix)

How to model input to achieve such senario ?

The reference paper is :
http://aclweb.org/anthology/P/P16/P16-1100.pdf